# Is "frontend" generic term or it is used only in web design?

Tags: architecture, terminology, software

When I read about frontends, it always mentiones webpages. Can it be used in different contexts, e.g. desktop applications?

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177143/where-does-the-term-front-end-come-from/177170#177170

Answer (score 14):

The term is generic and it tends to be used in n-tiered applications and refers to the UI.

It is not limited to n-tiered applications - in a single tiered application, if you have good separation of layers (say UI, business logic and infrastructure), you would still refer to the UI as the front-end.

So, you can use it whenever you are specifically talking about the UI - the interface that the end user uses.

Comment: Hm, I had a very different definition of front end. I'm wondering if there is a difference in interpretation between USA (front end = UI) and Europe (front end = part of a system which would be accessed by users).

Comment: @MainMa - Don't know. For me a UI == part of a system which would be accessed by users...

Comment: @MainMa In my mind the UI encapsulates (or is) the part that the user accesses; so is indeed the front end whichever way you look at it. By definition a UI doesn't need to be graphical; UI != GUI

Comment: For me UI means just one layer in the application(s) which run on the client side of a CS system. And those applications are often called the front end.

Answer (score 3):

The term is used both in design and development, including development of desktop software. The term targets a part of a system which is intended to be accessed by a customer or a user.

**1. In web development:**

It is not unusual to make the difference between:

- Front end: the website or web application itself, as it is used by people outside the company,
- Back end: the part of the web application which is used only by people with specific permissions and which allows them to execute administrative tasks.

Note: moderators would be qualified as people outside the company, so controls used by moderators are part of front end.

**2. In SOA/SASS:**

When services are involved, front end would be everything directly accessible by the users/customers. A desktop application installed by the user and which connects to a bunch of web services would be qualified as front end.

Services themselves, in this context, would be excluded from the front end.

Note: if a web service *is* the actual product, it may be qualified as a front end. For example, Twilio web service is the front end.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has an article that answers this question directly, [front and back ends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends).

In the context of compilers:

- **Front end** validates the syntax and semantics then outputs some intermediate representation, such as an AST.
- **Back end** generates the assembly or translated code.